# Transparent screensaver for linux?

Tags: linux, security, screensaver

I want to have a few console windows running `tail -f` on logs. Unfortunately this means that anyone with access to the computer can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and have shell access.

So I want to lock the screen while still leave everything on the desktop visible.

So has anyone heard of a transparent screensaver or do you have a better idea on how to solve my problem?

Comment: in this case the preferred DE and distro might be useful. 
Also, see this SU thread for ideas http://superuser.com/questions/72172/temporarily-disable-touchpad-and-keyboad-i-e-babyproofing-my-linux-laptop - http://sourceforge.net/projects/lk4b/ specifically looks promising, but i haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This trick works for me:

```
$ xlock -mode blank -geometry 1x1
```

However, don't forget that for mission critical servers which hold private data, a screen saver is not enough. Screen savers are programs, they may eventually have bugs. Sometimes they segfault and that may be the reason for unwanted people to get access. During 10 years of linux I've seen xlock segfaulting a couple of times. Fortunately, only on my home workstation which was physically safe from intruders :-)

Comment: I find it is such a design mistake to unlock the screen when the screensaver dies badly... I guess that killing the X11 server would be much more secure in case a screenserver exits with non-zero.

Answer (score 9):

This question is old, but in case people stumble across it, I use xtrlock for this purpose:

```
$ apt-cache show xtrlock
[...]
Description-en: Minimal X display lock program
 xtrlock is a very minimal X display lock program, which uses nothing
 except the Xlib library.  It doesn't obscure the screen, it is
 completely idle while the display is locked and you don't type at it,
 and it doesn't do funny things to the X access control lists.
```

Changes the cursor to a padlock but otherwise makes no visible changes.  To unlock, hit Enter, type password, hit Enter (there's no prompt).

Comment: Thanks! Works for me in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

What about running those `tail -f` in `screen`, then detach from the screen and run `vlock`?