# How do I disable the CD drive eject button in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc, eject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable CD eject button on laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/8770/disable-cd-eject-button-on-laptop)

My baby brother keeps messing around with the CD drive. I tried the software from [Disable CD eject button on Windows laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/8770/disable-cd-eject-button-on-laptop) but it didn't work on Windows 7. I'm using a desktop computer with Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried **[CD/DVD Drive Locker](http://www.softbureau.com/index.html)** and it worked on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit.

> If you have small children in your
>   family, then you are probably familiar
>   with the situation in which straight
>   after they learn to move around
>   independently, they begin to touch
>   everything that they came across.
>
> In particular, children like to open
>   and close the CD/DVD drive on the
>   computer, and press the Reset button.

**The CD/DVD Drive Locker helps to temporary turn the CD/DVD ROM drive off**, and so pressing on the CD/DVD drive's buttons doesn't lead to the CD/DVD drive being ejected.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote LockCD application after giving up on finding a properly functioning software that would lock the CD ROM eject button which i hit quite frequently on my Lenovo T520 laptop. The main problem with the software found over the internet was that it wouldn't retain the lock state after Sleep/Resume. I made it freely available at http://sourceforge.net/p/lockcd/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 2):

If the CD-ROM button is activated by one of those little plastic tabs built into many cases, you could physically remove the tab from the case.

You could still eject via the software command in windows.

However, it sounds like you might have a laptop? In that case you could physically remove the drive. Or remove your baby brother from the computer area :)

Answer (score 1):

cd-rom lock is working successfully on Windows 7 Ultimate. All you have to do is go to google and search `msinet.ocx` and put that small `.ocx` into the `C:\Windows` folder. After that, you can select English language from the options.

Answer (score 0):

here's a similar program (but i don't know if it works for Windows 7 x64):

**[CDRom-Lock](http://download.cnet.com/CDRom-Lock/3000-2094_4-10424451.html)**

> This aptly named utility prevents your
>   CD and DVD drives from being opened
>   with an eject button. CDRom-Lock has a
>   no-frills interface that lets you
>   select a CD/DVD drive from a drop-down
>   list, lock or unlock it, and open or
>   close the drive.

Comment: this immediately crashed when i tried it