# Can I disable my DVD drive from ejecting?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, eject

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I disable the CD drive eject button in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/94603/how-do-i-disable-the-cd-drive-eject-button-in-windows-7)

My desktop sits on the floor under my desk and occasionally I will accidentally bump the DVD drive eject button with my knee. Rather than move the desktop or stop being clumsy, I'd prefer to just disable the drive from ejecting at all. Is there a setting in Windows 7 that will do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is handled on the level of the drive firmware and NOT the operating system, which is not to say that there might not be some third party hack for it but I've never heard of such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

My cats will do something similar with my printer (creating test pages). I solved it by taping a piece of 1/4" cardboard over the button. Taping only one end of it allows me to "flip" it up, similar to a covered toggle switch.

[image: Covered Toggle Switch]