# Disable laptop CD-ROM drive

Tags: laptop, compact-disc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable CD eject button on laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/8770/disable-cd-eject-button-on-laptop)
>   ** The answers are not duplicate : should leave both questions or move answers **

Since I seldom use the built-in cd-rom, but usually carelessly press open door button which is on the side of laptop. Is there any way to power off cd-rom so the button won't work. Better not to open the back lid and unplug power cable.

Comment: dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/8770/disable-cd-eject-button-on-laptop

Answer (score 3):

Some possible solutions.

[CDRom-Lock](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cdrom-lock/)

> This small programme blocks the eject
>   button at almost every CD/DVD drive
>   and gives the user the power of
>   controlling the CD/DVD drive by a
>   small icon at the windows system tray.

[Toddler Keys](http://tk.ms11.net/)

> This is a little program I wrote to
>   protect my computer from my daughter.
>   It is a useful tool for parents that
>   allows you to lock your computer
>   keyboard, CD drive doors and power-off
>   button. When the keyboard is used it
>   will display images and play sounds
>   every time a key is pressed, thereby
>   preventing access to the desktop and
>   applications, while adding some
>   entertainment value for the kid.
>   You can select the images and sounds
>   to be used by copying them to the
>   Toddler Keys folder. To exit the
>   locked screen, just type the word
>   QUIT.

Answer (score 2):

Most laptops will allow you to remove the drive and replace it with a empty bay or extra battery. However as mentioned you could try the Windows Device Manager if you're on Windows.

Because it's most likely controlled by the motherboard, next place I'd check would be the BIOS settings and see if you can disable the controller. Or just crack the case and unplug it.

From the other question, it appears that [CD Drive Locker](http://www.softbureau.com/index.html) will do the trick.

Comment: I disabled it in Windows Device Manager. But it seems only remove the disk drive from explore but the button is still working. Also, I would like to find a way through software/firmware to turn it off, so some day if I need it again, it will be easier to restore. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer.